# Incorporating JQuery into Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

hate to be asking this question again but none of the other solutions have gotten it to work for me. I'm a complete newbie to this, but I'm trying to incorporate some simple JQuery into my website on Rails.

In my app\views\application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery', "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Also read somewhere to include in the footer:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag(:application) %>
```

But that seems to be repetitive.

In my app\assets\javascripts\application.js I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

So it's commented out, not sure if that's right?

And finally I have my simple jquery code in a 'main.js' in the same folder:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('img').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$('img').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: the commented out part looks correct.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? How do the results differ from what you expect?

Comment: also, yes, it is repetitive to include jquery in your app view twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it in application.js and

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

should work for you. No need to declare / load it seperately in your layout.

To load your main.js file, you need to specify that as well, in your application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require main.js
```

requiring file will give you much better control, than requiring tree. Loading jQuery twice/thrice could also caused you problem.

Answer (score 0):

the commented part is not really comments, its a notation used by sprockets `//=` to know what files to include when creating application.js. application.js is basically a manifest file (as written in the comments on the top of the file

to make jquery happen, and to be able to use `//= require jquery` make sure to have jquery gem installed with `gem 'jquery-rails'`

also, include the jquery in the header, not the footer, since onload javascript won't work on it